# Replace audio stream from one file with audio stream from another

Tags: sound, video, conversion

I have got two video files: .mp4, with a single (incorrect) audiostream, and an .mkv, with two audio streams (one incorrect, the other correct)

Is there a way to replace the audio of the .mp4 file with the second stream in the .mkv?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to extract the audio from the MKV first and then combine remux the MP4 with the new track. Something *like* this should work:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -acodec copy -vn audio.ext
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i audio.ext -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:1 -map 1:0 final.mp4
```

Comment: Hey, I extracted the audio properly using `ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -map 0:2 -ac 2 aud.wav` but still can't merge it with the mp4 file for some reason...

Comment: Hi @CookieMonster.  How was this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, with **avconv** (same as ffmpeg)

Try:

```
avconv -i INPUT_FILE_WITH_BROKEN_SOUND.mp4 -i SECOND_INPUT_FILE.mkv -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:1 OUTPUT.mp4
```

**-c copy** copies tracks instead of re-encoding them

**-map 0:v:0** selects track to be copied to output: 1st file -> video tracks -> 1st video track

**-map 1:a:1** selects track to be copied to output: 2nd file -> audio tracks -> 2nd audio track

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could down-voter tell why it is wrong?